# CustomEvent.detail not storing objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a `CustomEvent` and dispatching it as so

```
var event = new CustomEvent('Marketing', {
    detail: body.innerHTML;
});
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

This works fine, however, if I change detail to include an object as so

```
var event = new CustomEvent('Marketing', {
    detail: {
                body: bodyObj,
                email: emailStr
            }
});
window.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Then the detail in the event I receive in the Listener is `null`. Could someone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: Could you put your full code in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: You must doing something wrong, here is working example http://jsfiddle.net/8vq7tkan/

Comment: Can you add the contents of `bodyObj` to your question?
Because this works:
`var event = new CustomEvent('Marketing', {
    detail: {
                body: {hi:"bye"},
                email: "hi@hi.com"
            }
});
window.dispatchEvent(event);`

Comment: var bodyObj = document.querySelector('div[aria-label="Message Body"]');
This was causing the problem, simply sending out the .innerHTML and .innerText strings fixed it.